# I am Not sure if Analyze/Optimize table in MySQL(InnoDB) processed or not?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Steps: 
1. Tried to rebuild index using the following options in MySQL(InnoDB) Workbench.
2. On click of the "Analyze table"/ "Optimize" table we immediately got a ok response within seconds without any background process
3. Not sure if indexes has been built accordingly.

How can we understand if rebuild index process has been completed and how can we validate it?
[image]

Comment: How big is the table?  Rebuilding 1K rows might seem "instantaneous".

Comment: And on this day, little Karthik learned why we need to understand how things work before asking silly questions while using GUI programs and clicking options we don't understand. Right Karthik?

Answer (score 0):

- Compare the value of `SHOW TABLE STATUS` before and after the `OPTIMIZE`.  (`ANALYZE` does not rebuild the index.)  If the indexes were rebuilt, the values *may* change.
- If the table is only a few thousand rows, the rebuild will be so fast that you will have trouble noticing it.
- You can get finer control by using the mysql commandline tool instead of Workbench.
- `OPTIMIZE` is essentially never needed for Innodb tables.